# Using Autolayout and universal storyboard super view is not taking the full screen?

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I am developing an iOS application using Universal Story board and autolayout. The base views of my view controllers are leaving a space at the bottom and are not taking the full height of the screen. What could be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to property area in the storyboard and choose your main view then select all the lines which is available in that area. then it holds the full view of the page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your view is taking up the whole screen but is hidden behind a tab bar.

This will happen when you include them inside of a `UITabbarController`. The reason they reach down underneath the tab bar is because it is translucent (you can see a blurred version of the view through it).

This tutorial from Ray Wenderlich gives a good example and explanation of how to set this up in a storyboard.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Actually the "Show Toolbar" option for my navigation controller was checked. The space at the bottom was taken by the toolbar.
[image]

[image]